# youtube:merge an array of video files and upload as a single video

Tags: codeigniter, upload, merge, youtube

I have an array of video files which has to be merged and uploaded to youtube. For uploading I followed the instruction as per the url https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/codeigniter_library

But the merging process takes pretty amount of time.

Is it possible to pass a series of video files into youtube which then has to be merged there itself and then uploaded as a single video into youtube account?All this has to be done programmatically in php.

Comment: Well,you should extend that library or add one more method in it for doing so..

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Are there any helpful tutorials for doing so?

Comment: In CI, a library is nothing but a simple class...You can add methods in it just like you do it for your controllers.. So,understand the flow of that youtube library and create a function on your own which does the merging

Comment: Is the fact that it takes time the issue? Can you identify what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think use CodeIgniter to do this task is a nonsense.

There is no web frameworks (which just display pages and play a little with the database) was thinked to do long time process tasks.

There are many ways to do.

Me, I would add a task in a database and a worker will check this database every X minutes or hours and do the job. When the task is done, it will send you an email or post the video on YouTube if you want that.

You can check this [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html) to see how CodeIgniter works in CLI and this library to work with videos : http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/